# python set comprehension made out of different lists

Tags: python, set, python-2.6

```
expected = {
    'l1': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],
    'l2': ['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
}
```

I would like to get `set(['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'])` using python 2.6+ (so `{x for x in ...}` is not what I want).

I've tried

```
all_files = set(files for files in expected.values())
```

but it throws:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> expected = {
...     'l1': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],
...     'l2': ['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
... }
>>> set(f for files in expected.itervalues() for f in files)
set(['jkl', 'abc', 'ghi', 'def', 'mno'])
```

or using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(expected.itervalues()))
set(['jkl', 'abc', 'ghi', 'def', 'mno'])
```

BTW, Use [`dict.itervalues`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.itervalues) instead of [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.values). You don't need all that lists at once.

Comment: can you explain me why does set expect hashable type? All python design choices are logical, but I can't see the reason yet.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, Data structures like `set`, `dict` uses hash value internally.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, Read [Why must dictionary keys be immutable? -- Python Design and History FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable)

Answer (score 0):

```
set(sum(expected.values(),[]))
```

will get following result:
set(['jkl', 'abc', 'ghi', 'def', 'mno'])

since what you expected is set, forget the order

Comment: This should be avoided. It creates many list, deletes them; cause O(n**2) complexity.

Comment: Why do you think so?  See [this timeit result](http://ideone.com/nJRUtI). If you put more to the dictionary, it will get a lot slower (relatively to other versions): [Another timeit result - 1000 entries](http://ideone.com/a47KAt)

Comment: you're right, this method become slow as the length up